# Screensaver doesn't come back after display turns off

Tags: macos, screensaver

I have setup WebViewScreensaver to show a dashboard, and the password is required afterwards. This works well, except that when the display turns off after a few minutes, I turn it back on and cancel the password prompt, the display turns off immediately. I would like to have the screensaver come back for a few minutes instead. Is there a way to do this?